# Removing error popup of a specific control of jquery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery Validation Engine to validate my from.

I want to hide error message of a specific control manually.

```
$('#formID1').validationEngine('hideAll');
```

This hides all the error popups .
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `hide` instead of `hideAll`, and the id of the "control" instead of the form as selector.

as stated in [doc](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/),

> The hide method can be applied to a form or a field. It closes/hides
>   error prompts.

so

```
$('#yourSpecificControl').validationEngine('hide');
```

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't work that time. but after seeing the link you provided, I tried it again and this time it worked.. :) any ways.. Thank you.